# HTTP-404 header doesn't seem to work in server log

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I've built a dynamic website and modified the .htaccess file for static URLs and I need to create a 404 page for SEO.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

I'm using the above PHP `header()` function when there is no matching link in database, but when I check the server logs it seems like this does not work and gives `HTTP 200 OK` status code.

Here's the line from the server log:

```
[My IP] - - [12/Jun/2011:01:47:38 +0300] "GET /4k.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3284 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
```

`4k.html` is the link which does not exist.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you serving the 404 PHP script? It might be that Apache considers your method fine and logs a 200 even though your PHP script returns 404.

Comment: well I'm checking if the link exists in database at the top of the page, if not, I use the http 404 script in the regular content page and I don't change any meta or head tags except title,
so is this a normal situation?

Comment: Apache can not check a database .. you are already executing a PHP script at this point. How/where are you calling that PHP script?

Comment: @Onur Can you try `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true);` or even `header("Status: 404 Not Found");` if you are using FastCGI under Apache

Comment: You're sure that you're not outputting any data to the client before the header? Once any output has been sent back to the client, the header will be ignored.

Comment: @Chandranshu Nope, no data outputting before header 
@LazyOne I tried both but same result
@Frits van Campen with a simple if else statement right before outputting the doctype
and I tried to include a 404.html  then die() function after the header script, html file is being called but I still get 200 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are rewriting all files to a single PHP file so PHP can read it and do what it needs to do to serve a page. That means that Apache's handling of 404 pages is going to be, essentially, overridden. At this point it is up to your PHP file to serve a page or display a 404. As far as Apache knows, the request resulted in an HTTP code of 200, because it doesn't play any part after it triggers PHP to parse the script and give the output to the client that requested it.

In your PHP script, you will be doing checking to see if the page exists or not. If the page exists, show the page, else, give a 404 message. By putting `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true);` in your PHP file at the point where you know it's a 404, it will send the 404 header to the client, and therefore it was done correctly. To verify it is being sent correctly, trigger a 404 (by putting in a bogus url) and view the request details in Chrome Developer tools, you should see under Response headers that you are being sent a 404, while your Apache logs display a 200.

Comment: it also seems 200 in developer tools, it's written request URL <domain>/4k.html, request method:GET, status code:200 OK
I also call some js and css files in 404 page, does it effect the result?

Comment: No, it would not affect the result. Every new asset (js, css document, image, etc)  is its own separate request. Verify you are looking at the web facing document: http://i54.tinypic.com/mr4hnk.jpg Instead of saying 200, it should say 404. Next, try placing that header snippet at the top of your PHP file and see if you can just get that 404 to trigger.  EDIT: didn't see your most recent comment - Try removing the 2nd argument to that header() function.

Comment: I put the header script at the first line of the page and server still says " Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at.. " I think it's caused by server

Comment: Finally I've made it work.I've disabled the Unicode Signature (BOM) and it worked 
and no idea what that's for.. :)

Comment: Ah, that would do it. BOM is called the Byte Order Mark, which a text editor will place in the file. It is useless in this situation. Headers are sent through the first few lines of the HTTP response, and by having that BOM there, you are preventing PHP from sending any more headers.